# cross checking two ArrayList to find a text that contains some words

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

Here I have two Array Objects, but each one contains different type of object.
children contains a State object//looks like this `Nh3 Kf6 20. Ng1 Kg6 21. Nh3 Kf5 22. Rb1`
enemyLocation is an object with String name and String position,// name does not matter for this, location looks like this //f5, it can be any combination of letter/number.

I need to check and see if children contains any enemy.position on them

for example:

```
child = Nh3 Kf6 20. Ng1 Kg6 21. Nh3 Kf5 22. Rb1
enemy.position = f5
```

This return null, however I want it to return true because child contains f5 in Kf5. I understand it is different but I want to return true if this combination is found. case sensitive.

```
for (State child: children) {
    for (Enemy enemy: enemyLocation) {
        System.out.println("children: " + child.toString()); // Nh3 Kf6 20. Ng1 Kg6 21. Nh3 Kf5 22. Rb1
        System.out.println("enemyLocation: " + enemy.position.toString()); // f5

        if (child.toString().contains(enemy.position.toString())) {

            target = child;

        }
    }
}
```

the other issue I am facing, is the nested loop, I am not sure how I can optimist that; I wanted to use 
something like below, but this will return only true/false without telling me which on of the children is the that = enemy

```
if (children.toString().contains(enemy.toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming different enemy positions, you can use the indexOf method built into the String class to acquire the child that matches it.

```
if(children.toString().contains(enemy.toString())){
    String[] temp = Arrays.toString(children).split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']\\s");
    int index = Arrays.asList(temp).indexOf(enemy.toString());
    target = children[index - 1]; //the -1 is due to brackets being part of 
    //string 
    //or children.get(index) depending on what type of array object you're 
    //using
}
```

Comment: I give it a try, how but I am not sure if this will work due to the issue that I stated at the beginning.

Comment: Noticed a tiny error in the code provided. Here is the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this, It might work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Nh3 Kf6 20");
        list.add("Ng1 Kg6 21");
        list.add("Nh3 Kf5 22");
        list.add("Rb1");
        String enemy = "f5";
     int index = list.parallelStream().filter(x -> x.indexOf(enemy) > 0).mapToInt(x -> x.indexOf(enemy)).max().orElse(0);// You can directly get index using this function, It will return 0 if there is not any matches found else will return last index(As we have used max)



    }
```

Comment: I am giving it a try,  can you please explain this line ```        if (list.parallelStream().filter(x -> x.indexOf(enemy) > 0).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() > 0) {
``` also how can I find the index of the matched child?

Comment: That is a Java 8 function which will stream list internally. To get a index you can use 
System.out.println(list.parallelStream().filter(x -> x.indexOf(enemy) > 0).map(x -> x.indexOf(enemy)).collect(Collectors.toList())); That will provide list of indexes.

Comment: This will give you index as int direclty.int index = list.parallelStream().filter(x -> x.indexOf(enemy) > 0).mapToInt(x -> x.indexOf(enemy)).max().orElse(0);

Comment: Let me know if you face any issue or confusion